# Android binding to Service

Tags: android, service, ipc

I'm binding to a Service, using `context.bindService(bindIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`. This method returns `true`. But I don't get connected. Some code:

```
// Snippet from method, that connects to service:
boolean result = context.bindService(bindIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
Log.d(TAG, "is connected: " + connected);
return result;
}

// Connection:
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            parser = Parser.Stub.asInterface(service);
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected to service...");
            connected = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            parser = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected from service...");
            connected = false;
        }

    };
```

Eventually, I don't get into `onServiceConnected` method: no messages in logcat except for `D/FrameworkBridge(  926): is connected: false`.
Any ideas?

**UPD:** I commented immediate call to service method (that was throwing NPE) after I connect to it, and everything worked well: the service is started and binded to. Seems like the connection is created in a separate thread, or so. Is there any way I can make my class wait, util the connection is actually established?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in to the same issue and found out that I had to call startService as well to get it working: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)

This is what my code looks like:

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WeatherService.class));

bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
                WeatherService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Just called `context.startService(bindIntent);` right after call to `bindService` method. Did not help, same problem.

Comment: Made modifications to my code to be similar to yours. Still no luck. I'm also calling `startService` and `bindService` from the class, that is not an `Activity` and does not have it's own `Context`. It is an utility class, that accepts `Context` as a constructor parameter, and then uses it to start and bind to service. Could that be relevant?